# ProgressDialog window is showing in Black color

Tags: android

The two lines below are used to display a progress dialog in my project. These lines are behaving differently in different projects.

one project is showing Black window and another is showing White window.[image]

[image]
    ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SignUpOptionsActivity.this, "","Fetching data", true);
      ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

I just likes to know why this different behaviour and how can I get my window to be white color always.

Comment: yo can change this in the manifest,
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar"

Comment: It may be your project Theme. Check if the theme is the same on your two projects manifest files.

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" by changing to above given android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar"  my screen is getting left and right gaps